# Referral System in IOS?

Tags: ios, referrals

I implement referral system in Android like this way.

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.poster&referrer=50380
```

So in my application i get referrer code and use it but i cannot find any way in ios like this.
Can you please tell me anyway so when user click on Specific Link he redirect to AppStore and install application and after install application app get referrer code.
Or any supposed way to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use deep links for that and then can achieve the required results. There are multiple tutorials on how to implement Dee-links. You can use Branch.io for that. Here is a tutorial on How to implement deep link using Branch:- https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/ios-universal-links-and-app-referrals-using-branchio-integration-31dd474be20

Answer (score -1):

What are you looking for is `Deferred Deep Linking` *(not to be confused with regular "Deep Linking")*, feel free to look it up.

You can build a solution from scratch, given you have a good understanding of the entire process. [Branch.io](https://www.branch.io/glossary/deferred-deep-linking/) gives a detailed description [here](https://www.branch.io/resources/blog/deferred-deep-linking-with-device-snapshotting/).

Otherwise, I would suggest you take a look at a third-party provider:

- [Reef Referral](https://www.reefreferral.com/)
- The already mentioned [Branch.io](https://www.branch.io/glossary/deferred-deep-linking/)
- [AppsFlyer](https://dev.appsflyer.com/hc/docs/dl_ios_ocds_ddl)
- [Singular](https://www.singular.net/glossary/deferred-deep-linking/)